# Using Imagick-resizeImage to create thumbnails creates dark images - PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am able to successfully resize (to the proper resized dimensions) an image that I have created from one page of a pdf document.  However, I do not understand why the result is a dark resized image with a patch of white.  Please, can someone advise?

PHP code:

```
 // Create image from first page of pdf document
 $im = new imagick('1Mpublic.pdf[0]');
 $im->setImageFormat('jpg');

 $imageHeight =  $im -> getImageHeight();
 $imageWidth = $im -> getImageWidth();

 $desiredImgWidth = 200;
 $desiredImgHeight = resizedImageHeight($imageWidth, $imageHeight, 
 $desiredImgWidth);

 $im -> resizeImage($desiredImgWidth, $desiredImgHeight, 
 imagick::STYLE_NORMAL, 1);


 // Save image
 $page = '1';
 $saveToFolder = 'thumbnailFolder';
 $fileName = 'thanhThumbNail_'.$page.'.jpg';
 $saveImgToPath = $saveToFolder.'/'.$fileName;
 $result = file_put_contents($saveImgToPath, $im);





 function resizedImageHeight($imgWidth, $imgHeight, $desiredImgWidth){

     $quoient = $imgWidth/$imgHeight;
     $height = $desiredImgWidth/$quoient;

     return $height;
 }
```

Resulting thumbnail image:

[image]

Link to original PDF can be found here:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4905263/pdf/ksgt-06-04-1091539.pdf

Comment: Please post a link to your original PDF. It is possible that it is CMYK or that there is transparency. JPG does not support transparency. Try saving to PNG and see if that helps. Check if the PDF is CMYK. If so, use the equivalent of -colorspace sRGB BEFORE reading the PDF.

Comment: @fmw42 i have added the link to original pdf above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PDF has transparency. JPG does not support transparency and shows black where the PDF was transparent. Just turn the transparency off. In Imagemagick command line:

```
convert -density 300 ksgt-06-04-1091539.pdf[0] -alpha off result.jpg
```

[image]

See setImageAlphaChannel at https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagealphachannel.php

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the background color is not defined. You need to set the background color *before* reading the PDF document.

```php
// Create image from first page of pdf document
$im = new imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor('WHITE');
$im->readImage('1Mpublic.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
```